# How to access data inside the textblock in DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I get data from `TextBlock Name="txtSellerId"`

```
<Grid Margin="10">
        <DataGrid Name="dgUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  LoadingRowDetails="dgUsers_LoadingRowDetails">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
<DockPanel Background="GhostWhite">
<grid>
<TextBlock Name="txtSellerId" Text="{Binding SellerId, StringFormat=d}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
                        </Grid>

                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>

            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Since you're binding values, why aren't you working with the data in your viewmodel rather than getting data back out the ui?

Answer (score 1):

To get value programmatically you can try this method

```
dgUsers.LoadingRowDetails += dgUsers_LoadingRowDetails;

 void dgUsers_LoadingRowDetails(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
       {
         var textBlockValue = (e.DetailsElement as FrameworkElement).FindName("txtSellerId") as TextBlock;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a model to data grid rows and use it in code-behind.

```
var user = (User)myDataGrid.SelectedItem;
var userId = user.Id;
```

An simple example: [DataGrid with row details](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/)